# New user registration problem in WordPress, Privacy Policy checkbox missing?

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, registration

I'm having a real issue enabling a checkbox on this page `https://www.tankservices.co.uk/my-account`

Just under the privacy policy there used to be a checkbox, now it's disappeared??

Not sure when it disappeared, it was brought to my attention when a new user could not actually register due to not being able to "accept the privacy policy". Not sure how to fix this.

Any ideas would be very helpful. Many thanks :)

WordPress Version           6.0.3
WooCommerce version:        7.0.0

Comment: Checkbox is actually still there, just being hidden via CSS for some reason. Check your theme's stylesheets, more specifically `_checkbox_radio.scss` and you'll find some rules in there that are causing this.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mp64tMGC7E6zoB0XB_wxa2hMG0deW3hH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can't really see anything in there to be honest , thank you for your reply

Comment: This is what I'm seeing: https://i.postimg.cc/4djKYfDg/Screenshot-2022-10-18-110318.jpg. If you're not familiar with SASS/SCSS and/or WordPress development in general it might be a good idea to reach out to the people who maintain your website and have them look into this for you.